# BroadcastReceiver not found in Manifest

Tags: android, bluetooth, xamarin.android, android-manifest, classnotfoundexception

I want to start a service on bluetooth turn on/off. But I am facing some issues. Here are a few things.
Here is the Manifest:

```
<application android:label="JustAnyLabel">

        <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

</application>
```

Here is the BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    private Intent theServiceIntent;
    public MyBroadcastReceiver () : base()
    {}

    public override void OnReceive (Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        string action = intent.Action;

        if (action.Equals (BluetoothAdapter.ActionStateChanged))
        {
            int state = intent.GetIntExtra (BluetoothAdapter.ExtraState, BluetoothAdapter.Error);

            bool bluetoothEnabled = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter.IsEnabled;

            switch (bluetoothEnabled)
            {
            case false:
                if(theServiceIntent != null)
                {
                    context.StopService (theServiceIntent);
                    theServiceIntent = null;
                }
                break;


            case true:
                if(theServiceIntent == null)
                {
                    theServiceIntent = new Intent (context, typeof(TheService));
                    context.StartService (theServiceIntent);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the error:
[image]

So basically, my class is not being found and I have no idea why.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: MyBroadcastReceiver is java class ?

Comment: no, i am using Xamarin Studio, so its all C# :)

Comment: then you dont know how to declare class in android is it ?

Comment: yes its Android. And thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And here is the solution:

- Don't put receiver tag in manifest if you are working on Xamarin Studio
- Make sure the intent you are passing is the right one (for bluetooth toggle => `android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED`)
- Also, in your `BroadcastReceiver` class, write annotation `[BroadcastReceiver]` and in `Service` class, write annotation `[Service]`

Comment: PLEASE DON'T WRITE YOUR ANSWER IN UPPER CASE LETTERS! It really makes you appear that you are yelling!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and this work fine for me. This is the registration:

```
<receiver android:name="packagename.BluetoothBR">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED"/>
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And it is the receiver:

public class BluetoothBR extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();

    if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
        Intent intentB;
        final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE,
                BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
        switch (state) {
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                // Stop service...
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                // stop service....
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                // init service ...
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

}

Hope it helps you!! :)

Comment: you mean put whole package name before class name in Manifest ??
deployment failure occurs.

Deployment failed because of an internal error: Unexpected install output:  pkg: /data/local/tmp/Estimotes.Estimotes-Signed.apk
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]

Comment: you should put the name of the package for example like this: com.name.package.YourReceiver

Comment: this is my package name
MyPackage.MyPackage
So it becomes:
MyPackage.MyPackage.MyBroadcastReceiver
and this line gives me the error mentioned in previous comment

Comment: put the name of the package in little letters

Comment: Then I dont know the reason. it may be because it is not a Java class. Can you use a Java class instead C# for the receiver??

Comment: Then i cant help you more. Sorry!